# Longhand Student, Spirited Rider, Deft Hurler Style

Tags: dnd-4e

I'm trying to make a mounted charger with the aforementioned feats (along with Spear Push, Polearm Momentum, and Pinning Challenge).

I've read some conflicting reports about whether you can use all the feats at the same time on Cleave. I'm not very knowledgeable when it comes to various errata and sources, I just use whatever's in the compendium - am I able to use these three feats simultaneously?